# If $F$ is a one-to-one function, then if $y \in ranF$, then$ f(f^{-1}(y)) = y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is not the proof given in the lecture, but I found a way that seemed far more intuitive to me, so I wanted to check if it was right.

$F$ is one-to-one, so there's only one $y : f(x) = y$.
If $y \in ranF$, there's exactly one $y : x \in domF,$ & $f^{-1}(y) = x$

If we then apply $f$ to $x$, we get $f(x)$, which $= y$.

Comment: I'm not sure what $f(f-1(y))$ means.

Comment: I assume he means $f(f^{-1}(y))$

Comment: Yeah, I do but couldn't see a way to write that. I also see (for whatever reason) that it's not formatted with the symbols I intended. Links on how to avoid doing that in the future would also be appreciated.

Comment: @Rory you need to use \$ formula $...

Comment: Re <<there's only one $y$:$f(x)=y$>> this happens to be the definition of the function btw. Also, this one-to-one definition is equivalent to bijection.

Comment: Mathematics, like C programming, is case sensitive. $F$ and $f$ are two different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the same case: just $f$ will do. $F$ is a different object.

$f$ being one-to-one does *not* mean that for every $x$ there is a unique $y$ with $f(x) = y$, this is what $f$ being a function means.

So suppose $y \in \operatorname{ran}(f)$, so by definition this means that there exists some $x \in \operatorname{dom}(f)$ with $f(x) = y$. This $x$ is unique (!) because $f$ is one-to-one (if there were two, two distinct points in the domain would map to the same $y$, which cannot happen for a one-to-one function, by definition). So we can fix this $x$, and so $f^{-1}[\{y\}] = \{x\}$.

And so clearly, $f[f^{-1}[\{y\}]] = \{f(x)\} = \{y\}$ and the statement in the title has been proved. I think this is what you were trying to say.